# Debugging JavaScript in Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: wpf, debugging, chromium-embedded

I have a WPF application which uses CEF to display web content. My question is, is there a way to debug the Javascript/Web parts inside a WPF application?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You may also use `ShowDevTools()` extension method ([source](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/28f43261b6616d4fe6b8b2d19b76454ba293d9b4/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L668))

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
browser.ShowDevTools(); // Opens Chrome Developer tools window
```

[image: CEFSharp Developer Tools window]

Comment: why i dont see this function before? Is it still exist in the latest version @Eido95?

Comment: @gumuruh yes, it is.

Comment: You need to add `using CefSharp;` to have this method as it is an extension method if you can't see it.

Answer (score 43):

Enable remote debugging in your application:

**C#** (CefSharp)

```
CefSettings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;
```

**C++**

```
CefSettings settings;
settings.remote_debugging_port = 8088;
```

then run your app and point your browser to `http://localhost:8088/` to access the Chromium developer console (the same you have in Chrome with **Ctrl+Shift+j**)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunatly CefSettings is not found in my application. I have the following usings: 

using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.Wpf;

Did I forgot anything?

Answer (score 30):

While the accepted answer is correct, it doesn't really have enough detail.

I got this working in CefSharp using the WinForms control in a WPF application. (the WinForms control seems to have better performance). The code for remote debugging will probably be very similar for the WPF control though.

```
var settings = new CefSettings { RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088 };
Cef.Initialize(settings);
WindowsFormsHost.Child = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
```

Then go to `http://localhost:8088/` in your browser.

Comment: You should mark it as an answer or @Sga should edit his to yours.

Comment: Only the OP can mark it as an answer I believe. No matter, upvotes will sort it out eventually.

Answer (score 6):

To use 'ShowDevTools()' you will need first verify if the browser is initialized.
An example solution:

```
//Add an event to check
ChromeBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += ChromeBrowser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;

//Declare the event method to be called
private void ChromeBrowser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, IsBrowserInitializedChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            ChromeBrowser.ShowDevTools();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be the answer, think you for saving my time.

Answer (score 4):

To open the Chromium Dev-Tools window you can do the following:

```
CefBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().ShowDevTools();
```

This is similar to Eido95's answer, but it doesn't require the extension methods, which essentially just wrap these method calls.

**NOTE**: The control needs to be initialized before calling this method can be called. If you're wiring-up and F12-like functionality this shouldn't be a problem. If you're trying to do this when the app is starting you will need to listen for the **ChromiumWebBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged** event

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can be to launch cef with --enable-chrome-runtime.
You'll have the fully featured debugger (link files on disk and edit them from the debugger)