# Can the URI be displayed to the user using CEFSharp?

Tags: cefsharp, winforms-to-web

In my Windows form application (WinForms), I'm using CEFSharp to open a web page. I want to modify the right-click context to allow the user to display the URL that was opened. Currently, the context has "Back", "Forward", "Print...", and "View Source"

Comment: You can customize the context menu using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_IContextMenuHandler.htm

Comment: CEF has debugging support! This answer gave me enough of what I needed
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31577099/139689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @amaitland got the ball rolling. Here is my implementation. I hope this helps someone else.

When you initialize your instance of the WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser, you set it's property MenuHandler to your instance of a IContextMenuHandler.

```
    chromeBrowser = New WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(uri)
    chromeBrowser.MenuHandler = New Classes.CefBasicMenuHandler()
    Controls.Add(chromeBrowser)
```

Your implementation of an IContextMenuHandler is where you can control the context menu.

```
Public Class CefBasicMenuHandler
Implements IContextMenuHandler

private const ShowDevTools as Integer = 26501
private const CloseDevTools as Integer = 26502
Private Const CopyUrlAddress as Integer = 26503

Public Sub OnBeforeContextMenu(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, parameters As IContextMenuParams, model As IMenuModel) Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnBeforeContextMenu
    '//To disable the menu then call clear
    model.Clear()

    '//Add new custom menu items
    model.AddItem(CType(CopyUrlAddress, CefMenuCommand), "Copy URL address")
    model.AddSeparator()
    model.AddItem(CType(ShowDevTools, CefMenuCommand), "Show DevTools")
    model.AddItem(CType(CloseDevTools, CefMenuCommand), "Close DevTools")
    model.AddSeparator()
    model.AddItem(CefMenuCommand.Reload, "Reload")
    model.AddItem(CefMenuCommand.Copy, "Copy")
End Sub

Public Function OnContextMenuCommand(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, parameters As IContextMenuParams, commandId As CefMenuCommand, eventFlags As CefEventFlags) As Boolean Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuCommand
    Dim commandId1 As Integer = CType(commandId, Integer)

    If commandId1 = ShowDevTools Then
        browser.ShowDevTools()
    End If
    If commandId1 = CloseDevTools Then
        browser.CloseDevTools()
    End If
    If commandId1 = CopyUrlAddress Then
        Clipboard.SetText(parameters.PageUrl)
    End If

    Return False
End Function

Public Sub OnContextMenuDismissed(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame) Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuDismissed
End Sub

Public Function RunContextMenu(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, parameters As IContextMenuParams, model As IMenuModel, callback As IRunContextMenuCallback) As Boolean Implements IContextMenuHandler.RunContextMenu
    Return False
End Function
End Class
```